# How to console out a recursive object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console

So, I have a generic object myObject

The problem is, myObject can contain self-referencences.

So if I do

```
console.debug(JSON.stringify(myObject))
```

it errors out because of recursion.

How can I console log this? Is there something like...

```
console.debug(JSON.stringify(removeRecursion(myObject)))
```

Comment: `console.log(myObject)` ?

Comment: Which console are you logging to, i.e. which environment are you using? In general, `console.log(myObject)` will deal with circular references in a suitable way.

Comment: @Bergi I'm in node.js

Comment: In that case, [node's `console`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html) is perfectly capable of logging object with circular references - just don't use `JSON.stringify`! It uses [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) internally, whose docs explain (and give an example) how it works.